# Spring Maven project splitted, deployment issues in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, m2e-wtp

I've got a Spring maven project separated, **myapp.web** contains only JSPs and static files, while myapp.core contains app context XMLs and Controllers.

**myapp.core**

--*src/main/resources/context.xml*

--*src/main/resources/mvc-context.xml*

**myapp.web**

--*src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml*

web.xml contains root context configuration and servlet configuration

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:/context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
    ...

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet0</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:/mvc-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet0</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I also have `OpenSessionInViewFilter` configured

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>flushMode</param-name>
        <param-value>AUTO</param-value>
    </init-param>

</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Now, generating the war from **myapp.web** and dropping in Tomcat manually works fine.
But, when running from Eclipse via "Run On Server", `OpenSessionInViewFilter` does not see `sessionFactory` which is configured in context.xml
I tried fixing build path of project but it won't run.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1079)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.lookupSessionFactory(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:242)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.lookupSessionFactory(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:171)
```

Now I know this is a **Eclipse/m2e-wtp** configuration issue since it's working by manually deploying  but I've been unable to fix it. Played with Build Path of project as is usually suggested but no success.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. 
The problem was this: Context was auto-reloading(not sure why)! **myapp.core** used to be the entry point(web app). After splitting, it had a missing tick on *Project Facets* called *Utility Project*, and Maven Integration for Eclipse was not deploying this project as a jar!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the xml files in myapp.core are at the classpath when you run your application via eclipse. Most likely they aren't. 
You can check by using something like

```
if (getClass().getResource("my context-xml file") ! = null) {
   System.out.println("No context file on the classpath, won't work");
}
```

Problem could be that Eclipse is configured no to copy the xml files to the bin directory.

Comment: Thanks, but contexts are found, because it doesn't show any `FileNotFoundException`. The problem is `OpenSessionInViewFilter` does not see `sessionFactory` which is in `context.xml`.